# SDL2.0.5 - SDL_KEYDOWN shows two identicle presses when only one key is pressed

Tags: sdl2, keyboard

SDL2.0.4 using this code:

```
SDL_Keycode key = 0;

while(SDL_PollEvent(&(Global->event)) != 0)
{
    if(Global->event.type == SDL_QUIT)
    {
        /* Allow users to exit the game */
        break;
    }
    else if(Global->event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
    {
        /* Actual Keypresses */
        key = Global->event.key.keysym.sym;

        if(key == getSDLKValue("p-key"))
        {
            /* ... p key is pressed */
        }
        else if(key == getSDLKValue("q-key"))
        {
            /* ... q key is pressed*/
        }
    }
}
```

Works fine to get a single `p` key press when the key is pressed down. However, when manually compiling, and using 2.0.5 logging shows that a single key press has:

```
Key pressed: 112
Key pressed: 112
```

It gets pressed twice in the window, when only once in reality.

Is this a bug with SDL2.0.5? Running on Ubuntu 16.04, manually compiled SDL2.0.5.

Comment: What if you print `.key.repeat` in both cases?

Comment: 0 for 2.0.4, and 1 for 2.0.5 first key press recorded, and 0 for second.

What does this mean?

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/a/27084554/5698848 will solve my problem, but I'm really curious why 2.0.4 -> 2.0.5 adds this "repeat" and what it is? Compiling it manually (2.0.5) vs a package manager (2.0.4) might have some `make` flags I didn't enable?

Comment: `.repeat` is meant to be used mostly for text input. Try to hold a button and after a moment you will start to receive a lot of "fake" keypresses with `.repeat == 1`. I don't think there are special flags to change the behaviour you're seeing. Something tells me that it's a small design decision.

Comment: I see. You can make your and my comments the post Answer if you want and I can accept, or I will do so in a few days.

Comment: I'm ok with you posting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`event.key.repeat` is `0` for actual key presses, and `1` for fake presses (which are generated if you hold a button long enough).

To fix this issue, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27084554/5698848) suggests to just check if `event.key.repeat == 0`.

It's possible that 2.0.5 behaves in the way described to make it easier to separately handle text and non-text input.